# Very slow regex perfomance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

My application is very slow and sometimes it take hours to become normal. When i used profiler i found the code where it is taking large amount of time which is nothing but the place where regex match occurs. Can any body guide me how to improve the perfomance. The code snippet is shown below

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\@[A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$|^$");
rx.IsMatch("john.gilbert.stu.seattle.washington.us");
```

Is there any way i can cache the patterns and reuse it?

Comment: If you have a complex regex, it could be [catastrophically backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: @Paul Phillips Is there any way i can cache the patterns and reuse it?

Comment: it all depends on how complicated is your regular expression and how big is the text your are processing

Comment: You need to show the regex and contents that are slowing it down.  Caching is not an obvious way to solve this.

Comment: @Paul Phillips i edited my question

Comment: Unlike some of the other messages convey here, the static methods do cache the regex - see this BCL team post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx
I'd be interested in testing the complexity of the regex - do simpler regex's perform significantly better? If so, identify the performance characteristics of your regex and tweak as-needed.

Comment: For complex matching a full-fledged parser such as [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) might be worth looking into.

Comment: Another note on your code: You should rewrite it as a single condition by merging the conditions inside each `if` with `&&` between. Then get rid of that long list of `retval = false`

Comment: As Paul said, you need to post the regexes you are using, as well as the strings you are testing them against.

Comment: It's hard to tell whether your regex is over-complex based on that one input value. Can you please supply some more examples, including the _most_ complex sample text you need to match? In the meantime, do you get a performance boost if you move `rx` to a field and add `RegexOptions.Compiled` to the constructor parameters?

Comment: The example string you provided doesn't match. We need some examples of strings you want to match to understand what you're trying to do. It looks like you want to validate email addresses, but it's hard to give good advice without knowing how much of the official email address format (which is very complex) you need to support.

Answer (score 3):

You can somewhat speed up RegEx by compiling and caching them, but it is very unlikely to solve performance issue on the scale you have. I.e. some slow RegEx that requires O(n^2) will not magically become O(n) due to caching/compiling or any other sort of automatic processing.

You need to review you regular expressions and validate if number of times each is executed. The fastest code is the code that does not need to run at all - so eliminate wasted matches if you have any first. You may need to switch to more appropriate way of parsing text (i.e. RegEx parsing of HTML is most likely wrong way - some good HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack combined with targeted queries may be more appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

If the strings aren't that complicated to parse I would just convert them to character arrays and parse them myself. It will dramatically improve performance. RegEx has very poor performance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.Length; i++)
{
     if (string[i] has some defining quality)
         if (string[i] meets second requirement)
         // break, change flag, ect.
}
```

Comment: @vettori I don't know what you're looking for in the strings but I'll edit with some pseudo code.

Comment: `array[i]` and `originalString[i]` will return the same character. Converting a string to a character array takes time and memory, so it may not be worth doing unless you need an array so you can edit its contents.

Comment: @SeanU Good point. Didn't know you could do that in C#. I wonder what is actually happening under the covers though... I may have to ask :)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal It just creates a new array of characters and then does a char-by-char copy of the string's contents into it.

Comment: @SeanU Thanks for the info. Edited to reflect this.